# How properly bundle&install python to windows users

Tags: python, windows, deployment, installation

I need to redistribute Python 2.6 for my users.

Currently, I execute the silent instalation for the msi installer from http://www.python.org/download/, but I have some problems, like if other version of python is installed this not get the default.

In the other hand, despite this could be rare, if a user have already python and I install my own, then could cause a conflict.

So, which could the best curse of action? How automate this install?. I already have http://installbuilder.bitrock.com but the available django stack is too large for my app, and I need to pre-install several python modules.

I wonder if in this case virtualenv will be the best option, but still have the issue of properly install it...

Comment: This is probably not helpful, but do you really need to distribute Python as a regular install?  There are things like py2exe which in concert with installer builders like InnoSetup will let you deliver executables to users without interfering with local Python installs, or other issues.

Comment: I can't use py2exe because is for a server that can accpet scripts/plugins in python, so I need the full python distribution...

Comment: @mamcx, that should in no way be a real issue.  Even though an app is py2exe'd, it is still capable of importing from the filesystem and of using functions like execfile().  Maybe a separate question asking about that would give you a straightforward solution and make this particular question moot.

Comment: Is for a plugin-capable system. I ship a python module (the SDK) to use my server, so is thje other way around: the plugins load the SDK. Also, this will work on OSX & Linux so having 2 ways of do things will complicate the things. Py2Exe is only a solution to deploy single scripts, not for something like deploy a webserver (my app is a web server-like soft)

Comment: I'll accept that you know best what you need for this situation.  Another note though: we've also used py2exe successfully to package up a Pylons-based web server application that is installed as a Windows service, so there again there's no inherent problem with using py2exe for more than a "single script".

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it, beyond some initial research, but ActiveState's [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/) generally does what you want, if you're looking for a commercial pre-built solution.

I have worked on software that included its own bundled Python, and there were never any problems with conflicts.  In our case, it was installed alongside the rest of the software, rather than C:\Python26, and it was intended for the software's use only, not as a replacement for any existing Python on the system.  A full Python with the stdlib pre-compiled to .pyo takes only ~10-20MB of space, depending on which modules you include.  So I wouldn't worry about the possible redundancy.

It also makes your life easier to have your own copy, since you know exactly which versions of all the third-party libraries you have; you don't have to worry about the user upgrading something that breaks your app.  The counter-argument is that some users may want the latest versions of libraries, for security reasons.  But in my experience, those users are in a very slim minority, and for them it just boils down to a little more work.

Finally, I presume you have reasons for wanting a full Python installation.  Just in case you're only interested in a way to distribute a single app, take a look at [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).

Comment: Yes, it's commercial, so you have the disadvantage of cost, and the possible advantage of support.  You didn't mention any cost requirements, so I put it out there as an option.